# White hole region in Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates and geodesic

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, geodesics, white-holes

We use Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates$(T,X)$ to describe black hole and white hole.

For $r>2GM:$

$$T = \left(\frac{r}{2GM}-1\right)^{1/2}e^{r/4GM}\sinh\left(\frac{t}{4GM}\right)\\$$

$$X = \left(\frac{r}{2GM}-1\right)^{1/2}e^{r/4GM}\cosh\left(\frac{t}{4GM}\right)$$

For $r<2GM:$

$$T = \left(1-\frac{r}{2GM}\right)^{1/2}e^{r/4GM}\cosh\left(\frac{t}{4GM}\right)$$

$$X = \left(1-\frac{r}{2GM}\right)^{1/2}e^{r/4GM}\sinh\left(\frac{t}{4GM}\right)$$

From Wiki, the graph of Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates can be divided into 4 regions. However, I cant get get both negative $T$ and $X$ from the above definition since $\cosh$ is always positive, then, how can we  obtain curves at the left bottom part of the graph?

[image: Source:wiki :Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates]

Also, I am wondering can I obtain some formula for drawing the geodesic on the graph other than radial null geodesic?

Answer (score 1):

I think probably the best equation to start from are (with $G = 1$)
\begin{align}
-T^2 + X^2 &= \left( \frac{r}{2 M} - 1 \right) \exp(\frac{r}{2M})
\end{align}
Here you can see that negating one or both of $T$ and $X$ does not modify the above equation, making it true in all patches. To solve for a particular patch you have to choose if $T$ and $X$ are greater than or equal to $0$ in the patch you want when you take the square root.

The other equation is
$$
\frac{T+X}{T-X} = \exp(\frac{t}{2M}).
$$
This equation holds for both the right and the left patch. When it comes to the the top and bottom patch, $t$ does not actually cover those patches. From the above equation, you can see how if the horizon is $T = \pm X$, that corresponds to $t = \pm \infty$. That means that you can't continue $t$ the $|T| > |X|$ region.

However, if you make the left hand side negative, as in
$$
\frac{T+X}{T-X} = -\exp(\frac{t}{2M}).
$$
then now you can get the upper and lower regions, but not the right and left regions. If you solve for $T$ and $X$ in terms of $t$ and $r$ in the region you want, you can get curves in any region you want.

Comment: I think your second and third equations are backwards. You could of course square the second equation and get one that's valid in all four regions (but not on the horizon).

Comment: @benrg how can we extend the 3rd equation beyond the horizon. $t$ is already infinity there. What will be the value of $t$ corresponding to $T$ and $X$ in that region because t is already infinity at the horizon.

Comment: You can't extend $t$ past the horizon, precisely because it's infinite there. You need to come up with a different definition of $t$ to use on the other patch.

Comment: @user1379857 what is the range of $t$ on that other patch according to whatever the new condition is....and is the new condition your eqn 3...can you tell me what is the range of $t$ in the other patch

Comment: That is a question without meaning. You cannot "extend" $t$ to the other patch. You need to set up a new coordinate system entirely, where $t$ has a new meaning. $t$ now becomes spacelike, instead of timelike, and it now runs from $\infty$ to $-\infty$, as indicated on the diagram in the OP.

Comment: @user1379857 sorry. But as far as I can see, we define the new Kruskal coordinates either $T$ and $R$ or $U$ and $V$ and we do not change the definitions of  $t$ or $r$. You said there is a different definition of $t$. What is that...What is the precise eqn/definition for $t$ in that patch.

Comment: The two final equations I wrote in my answer give the two different definitions of $t$ in the two different patches